# 文字列を変数として扱うにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか?

Tags: python

最近Pythonの勉強を始めた初心者です。
リストに入っている文字列を変数名として扱う方法を教えて頂けると助かります。(自力で検索をしてみたのですが、検索語彙が悪いのか解決出来ませんでした)

具体的には、
`li = ["inu", "neko", "ushi"]`というリストがあり、

```
inu = "wan"
neko = "nya"
ushi = "moo"
```

となっている時に、

```
for i in li:
 print(i) 


wan
nya
moo
```

このような動きが出来ればと思っています。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: `globals()` や `locals()` を使う方法もあります。`for i in li: print(globals()[i])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

このような形はどうでしょうか?

```
li = ["inu", "neko", "ushi"]
inu, neko, ushi = "wan", "nya", "moo"
for i in li:
  print(eval(i))
```

ただこの`eval()`というのはWeb系制作をする際にかなり脆弱性を持った処理となる為、ご質問の様な状況の際は`辞書`を使うことをお勧めします。

辞書は`key`と`value`という2つの値をお互いに関連付ける事が可能であり、今回の場合は以下の形でも実現可能です。

```
li = ["inu", "neko", "ushi"]
wanwan = ["wan", "nya", "moo"]
dict = {}
count = 0
for i in li:
  dict[li] = wanwan[count]
  count += 1

# dictの中身はこうなっています
# {"inu":"wan", "neko":"nya", "ushi":"moo"}

for i in dict:
  print(dict[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

関数を使わないとてもシンプルな方法としてこのような書き方もあります。

```
li = ["inu", "neko", "ushi"]
li2 = ["wan", "nya", "moo"]
li = li2

for i in li:
    print(i)
```